# Is it possible to exchange data in html pages through localstorage

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm newbie to this field. I'm trying to pass data between two html pages. It works properly fine when I run it on my own computer but when I upload it in hosting server what I see is that it doesnot update the result. I have a form which is rate exchange form. I update new rate from here so it is updated on my main page. It is not working when someone else visits my link he doesnot see any rate that I have updated. Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my code

```html
    <body><div class="profile" style="margin-top:100px;border-bottom: 4px ; border-color: #ed3330;">
        <center>
            
        <form action="">
            <div style="padding-top: 20px;" class="record">My sale rate</div><br><input id="sale" step="0.0001" type="number" required>
            <br>
            <div style="padding-top: 20px;" class="record">My purchase rate</div><br><input id="purchase" step="0.0001" type="number" required><br>
            <input class="submit" style="width: 200px;margin-top: 100px;" name="submit" type="submit" value="Click_To_update" onclick="myfunction()" >
        </form></center></div>
    </body>
    <script>
    function myfunction(){
        var purchase =document.getElementById("purchase").value
        localStorage.setItem("purchase",purchase)
        var sale =document.getElementById("sale").value
        localStorage.setItem("sale",sale)
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

This is my form where updated rate is shown

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
    let loop=0
    var purchase =localStorage.getItem("purchase")
    document.getElementById("buy").innerHTML=purchase
    var sale=localStorage.getItem("sale")
    document.getElementById("sell").innerHTML=sale
    myfun ()
              function myfun (){
                if (loop%2==0){
            $('#source_amount').keyup(function () {
             var sum = 0;
             $('#source_amount').each(function() {
                 sum =purchase* Number($(this).val());
                 sum=sum.toFixed(2)
             });
             $('#target_amount').val(sum);
              
         });
         
        }
        else {
         $('#source_amount').keyup(function () {
            var sum = 0;
             $('#source_amount').each(function() {
                 sum =Number($(this).val())/sale;
                 sum=sum.toFixed(2)
             });
               $('#target_amount').val(sum);
              
         });
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi! There is quite a lot of code to read through, so that it's hard to see what part you're asking for help with. Please could you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you're having, with clear expected and actual results.

Comment: I'm unsure, do you expect your friend to see data that you affected through localStorage? That won't happen, localStorage is for you only.

Comment: Sir is there any solution that can help me to achieve it ?

Comment: @IMSoP sir I have updated the code. I want help in localStorage set & get Item so my friend can also see through my link when I update something from my form. to other page.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser have a `localStorage` session. So when you are setting the rates, the values will only be available in your browser.

That means, if you are trying for someone else in another computer to see the changes you did in your application, you will need to persist that data to a place where you can access from both computers.

For that you need either a database or another way to persist the data you want to display in the other browser.

Comment: many thanks ! can you please tell me the way other than database ?

Comment: You should check [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) if dont want to setup the database yourself. There are many options to persist data (some safer than others) but for what you want it might be enough